# SQL Server + Windows Server CALs

Tags: sql-server, windows, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I've asked the same question on stackoverflow, but i think it suits here better since it's a problem not related to programming.

Scenario:

I want to build Business Intelligence system using Windows Server and SQL Server. SQL Server with SSAS instance and SSRS server are installed with Windows Server on one physical machine. My system has 200 users and 1 administrator. Each user has access with its own ceredentials to SSRS reports generated with data from SSAS cube. Since SSAS supports only Windows authentication users data must be stored in Active Directory (or maybe there is another way to store this data? if you know the way, please let me know).

My question is:

Having 200 active users in this BI system, how many CALs do i need for them, considering they are connecting to SQL Server data via SSRS and their credentials are stored in AD on Windows Server? Which option would be the best considering the smallest possible cost?

I need to know about sql server and windows server CALs when these products are used at the same time

I have absolutely no idea about MS licenses' politic so please present straight answer if possible :)

Comment: My advice is to work with a local reseller and/or call Microsoft.

Comment: Please see @ChrisMcKeown 's suggestion on licensing. We don't provide licensing help on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

To connect SQL users for one instance to another SQL instance it may not require the CAL licenses.

CAL license is required if more than two users connect to a same system remotely.

If you have requirement to login 200 User at a time to your Server only then you need 198 CALs.